# Flurry - How to track Android version?

Tags: android, flurry

Just integrated Flurry into an app.
Now trying to figure out how many users are using Android version lower than 4.0

I can't find any data with the basic tracking.
So what is the best approach to send the Android version info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to flurry and go to Tehnical > All Firmware Versions.